# linux pthread_suspend

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Looks like linux doesnt implement pthread_suspend and continue, but I really need em.

I have tried cond_wait, but it is too slow.  The work being threaded mostly executes in 50us but occasionally executes upwards of 500ms.  The problem with cond_wait is two-fold.  The mutex locking is taking comparable times to the micro second executions and I don't need locking.  Second, I have many worker threads and I don't really want to make N condition variables when they need to be woken up.

I know exactly which thread is waiting for which work and could just pthread_continue that thread.  A thread knows when there is no more work and can easily pthread_suspend itself.  This would use no locking, avoid the stampede, and be faster.  Problem is....no pthread_suspend or _continue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dispatch larger chunks of work to the threads, so that the cost of locking becomes a smaller % overhead? (The threads spend more time working and less time delegating the work?)

Comment: The work is large .... sometimes. Can't tell till you try it. And I did dispatch the work in a way that doesn't need locking at all...cept I haven't figured out the optimal low cost way to suspend and wake threads without locking...cond_wait locks a mutex for every thread that is awakened. It also doesn't let you wake just one thread.  Well I could make a condition for each thread.... argh....  There must be a better way.  cond_wait seems suitable for a user gui thread, but not for high speed transactions.

Comment: I'm gonna look at the source code tomorrow for cond_wait as well as perf test the signal and pipe methods vs cond wait.

Comment: If you're entering kernel space I don't think anything is gonna be as fast as you seem to want... and there's really nothing you can do to sleep without entering kernel space...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the thread wait for a specific signal.

Use [pthread_sigmask](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/pthread_sigmask/) and [sigwait](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/sigwait/).

Comment: +1 for a promising answer.  I will test this out tonight and give you the answer if it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to mention you MUST use `pthread_kill` to signal a specific thread, otherwise you can't predict which thread is going to resume.

Comment: We performed testing on this method and it turns out we were able to sleep and wake threads 40x faster than using a pthread_cond_wait.

Comment: Please, would you share your tests? People might benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

Have the threads block on a pipe read. Then dispatch the data through the pipe.  The threads will awaken as a result of the arrival of the data they need to process.  If the data is very large, just send a pointer through the pipe.

If specific data needs to go to specific threads you need one pipe per thread.  If any thread can process any data, then all threads can block on the same pipe and they will awaken round robin.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that such a solution (that is, using "pthread_suspend" and "pthread_continue") is inevitably racy.

An arbitrary amount of time can elapse between the worker thread finishing work and deciding to suspend itself, and the suspend actually happening.  If the main thread decides during that time that that worker thread should be working again, the "continue" will have no effect and the worker thread will suspend itself regardless.

(Note that this doesn't apply to methods of suspending that allow the "continue" to be queued, like the `sigwait()` and `read()` methods mentioned in other answers).

Comment: Note that signals are queued (at least on NPTL).

Comment: @jweyrich: Aye, you can do it with signals, since `sigwait()` effectively does an atomic unblock-wait-block.

Comment: When the dispatcher adds work to the circular work queue, it will check the corresponding circular suspended queue. A suspended thread at the same index as the work will be woken up. The waking thread clears its suspended flag. The dispatcher will from time to time scan the suspended queue looking for threads that didnt wake up (the race) and signal them again. At the end of processing that suspended scan needs to be repeated (perhaps with a 1ms sleep) until all threads wake and complete.  Since the race condition is rare I estimate 1/100 transactions will need the extra scan at the end.

Comment: What do you mean by atomic unblock-wait-block?

Comment: @johnnycrash: `sigwait()` requires that you have the signal you are going to wait on blocked in the thread's signal mask.  It then waits for that signal to occur (effectively unblocking it), and when it returns the signal is blocked again.

Answer (score 0):

May be try an option of pthread_cancel but be careful if any locks to be released,Read the man page to identify cancel state

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care which thread does the work? It sounds like you designed yourself into a corner and now you need a trick to get yourself out of it. If you let whatever thread happened to already be running do the work, you wouldn't need this trick, and you would need fewer context switches as well.

Comment: There is a pool of threads.  There is also a list of threads that are waiting for work to finish or are idle.  If the new work item happens to be a dependency for a waiting thread, i wake that thread; otherwise, I wake an idle thread.  The signal lets me target a particular sleeping thread, or the first idle thread.  I rolled my own work queue that used atomics instead of mutexes and condition variables.  This kept the overhead low enough to maintain performance even if the work items took microseconds.  I just needed  to be able to sleep a thread occasionally like a mutex or cv.

Comment: @johnnycrash This sounds like bad design. Why have a specific thread waiting for a specific thing? You can be waiting for X to happen before doing Y without having a thread waiting. When X happens, then you arrange so *any* thread can do Y. Your design forces you into solving the problem of waking specific threads and then forces extra context switches and scheduler/cache penalties because that thread may be inefficient to execute at that time.