# Safe thread stack size?

Tags: c, pthreads, stack-size

I am writing some code that spawns quite a few threads (about 512 at the moment, but that could get higher in the future). Each of the threads only performs a small amount of operations, so I want the overhead that the threads place on the system to be kept at a minimum.

I am setting the stack size using `pthread_attr_setstacksize()`, and I can get the minimal allowed stack size from `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`. But my question is: **Is it safe to use `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN` for the thread stack size?** How do I go about calculating how much stack I need? Are there any hidden overheads that I will need to add on to my calculation?

Also, are there any other techniques I can use to reduce the threads' burden on the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reducing the thread stack size will not reduce overhead (not in terms of CPU, memory use or performance). Your only limit in this respect is the total available virtual address space given to threads on your platform.

I would use the default stack size until a platform presents problems otherwise (if it happens at all). Then minimize stack usage if and when problems arise. However these will lead to real performance issues, as you'll need to hit up the heap, or [devise thread-dependent allocation](http://www.cantrip.org/wave12.html) elsewhere.

Hidden overheads may include:

- Allocation of large arrays on the stack, such as by [VLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), [`alloca()`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Advantages-of-Alloca.html) or just plain statically sized automatic arrays.
- Code you don't control or weren't aware of the consequences of using such as templates, factory classes etc. However given that you did not specify C++, this is less likely to be a problem.
- Imported code from libraries headers etc. These may change between versions and significantly alter their stack, or even thread usage.
- Recursion. This occurs due to the above points also, consider things like `boost::bind`, variadic templates, crazy macros, and then just general recursion using buffers or large objects on the stack.

You can in addition to setting the stack size, manipulate the thread priorities, and suspend and resume them as required, which will significantly assist the scheduler and system responsiveness. Pthreads allow you to set contention scope; [LWP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_process) and in scope scheduling vary widely in their performance characteristics.

Here are some useful links:

- [Improving Performance through Threads](http://randu.org/tutorials/threads/)
- [linux pthread_suspend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994216/linux-pthread-suspend)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think this it closest to the answer I was After. I was hoping that someone was going to say "add up the sizeof() of all your local variables, add 42 bytes for the thread overhead and then add 10% for good luck", but it seems that there are potentially a lot more factors at play. Thanks for the tips on priorities and suspend.

Comment: @ltn100: no, it's more like "thoroughly test your code with a specified stack size, in a debug context which will detect overflow. Then add 10% for good luck".

Comment: @ltn100: If you can find a debug tool which actually measures high-water mark stack usage on your platform, that's good, but the platforms where you actually need to do this (because stack is physical RAM up front) aren't necessarily the ones with the best debugging tools. And you have to be *really* thorough with testing. Any little thing, including changes to libraries you dynamically link against, or environment variables they look at, or (literally) the day of the week, could increase your high-water mark. Avoid VLAs, avoid any recursion dependent on input data.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Right on. Nice terminology, and warning about external code/recursion.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be creating anywhere near that many threads, and you definitely shouldn't be making a new thread to do a small amount of operations. You should create a new thread if and only if your existing thread(s) are fully saturated AND there are more available physical or logical cares to do work. That puts a hard limit on a reasonable current application at about 10 threads or so, even if you ran on a hexacore you'd only need 12 or so at max. Such a design is very flawed, will use a huge amount of process memory, and won't really improve performance.

As for the stack size, you can't really compute how much you need for an arbitrary thread, as it totally depends on the code run. However, in Visual Studio, the typical stack size is a few megabytes. You would have to post the entire code AND the resulting disassembly executed by the thread to know how much stack size to use. Just stick it at a couple of megabytes.

Comment: +1: But you may want more threads than cores if your threads are regularly IO-bound...

Comment: @C. Ross: depends just how I/O bound they are. OK, so there are other ways of building an asynchronous I/O system that are more efficient in resources (and perhaps less efficient in my time, depending how good I am with event queues, `select`, etc), but if my threads are going to spend 99.8% of their time waiting for network I/O, then I would want 500 threads. Sometimes RAM is cheaper than programmers, sometimes it isn't ;-)

Comment: @DreadMG: Thanks for the response. Perhaps I should have been more explicit about the code I am writing. I _am_ very IO bound. I am trying to get close to the maximum number of IOPS that my SSD is spec'ed to allow (~16,000). I am reading many (~66,000) small (< 512B), sparse data blocks from a large file (~4GB). I need to retrieve this information as fast as possible. The optimum number of threads that I have found so far is about 512, but if I can reduce their overhead then perhaps I can use more. This is running on a dedicated server, and this its only job. Speed is everything!

Comment: @Steve True, True.  Make sure you're running 64 bit with a heap load of memory if that's what you want to do though.

Comment: @ltn100: You didn't mention that! :P If all you're doing is a little bit of I/O, then you probably don't need much stack space at all. I still think that if you're doing 512 threads, you must be doing something in your I/O code very, very wrong. Why not just memory map the whole file and read from the heap?

Comment: @DreadMG: Sorry, I was just trying to be concise with my question, but I guess it backfired! I have already tried using mmap, which is very quick when it hits the cache but very slow when it misses (it has to load the whole page [4096 bytes] even though I am only interested in a few tens of bytes). I have also tried AIO, and got into all sorts of trouble with that, but that's another story for another day...

Answer (score 5):

The required size of stack frames depend on the compiler you use, basically you could try to guess the size of your auto variables, parameters and some overhead for return adress, saving registers etc.

You should consider whether it would be an alternative to use a [Thread Pool](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/threads.aspx). Since the creation of a thread isn't for free.

Comment: I'm skeptical as to whether thread pools have significant benefit on modern implementations. Nobody uses `LinuxThreads` and hacks like that anymore. Do you have an up-to-date reference on relative cost of thread creation?

Comment: Indeed. Thread creation varies in cost, but generally it's cheap these days. However I think the point regarding thread pools still stands. They're a useful tool to consider, but I find that most people just try to find a reason to use them.